# Chrome Extension Simple Popup Won't Remain In Last State

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

Now I'm sure some of you have heard of the incident that happened at [Byron Nuclear Plant](http://sincedutch.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/1232012-alert-illinois-nuclear-plant-vents-radioactive-steam-blows-onto-downtown-chicago/) (Which I happen to live near) As well as a massive amount of earthquakes going on in the United States, and Canada. (**BTW**: I found [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bgldkmkikbbjidjkjeenngngfilfpmhg) extension where you can monitor earthquakes all over the world)

Anyway with all these issues going on I wanted to watch the Nuclear plants better, and I already knew about the [Radiation Network](http://www.radiationnetwork.com/) So I made a chrome extension called [Radiation Map](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icmkohlcddadeokjaabhanekikcdbalj?hl=en-US&gl=US) which is powered by the Radiation Network (Although I'm in no way affiliated with Radiation Network)

I made it so not just myself, but everyone can monitor Radiation Levels in the US, Japan, South America, and Europe. (I know I didn't do much work, but you see the reason)

However I have 1 problem that I can't figure out. When I have the popup open, and I'm viewing Japan's radiation levels, and when I close the popup it does back to showing the United States radiation levels. How do I make it so it stay's at where the user leaves it at, say in my case Japan in this example? (I tried content scripts, but the css, and jquery didn't load)

**Manifest**

```js
{
    "name": "Radiation Map",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "description": "See what radiation levels are anywhere in the United States, South America, Japan, and Europe! Updated in real time every minute.",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/logo.png",
        "default_title": "Radiation Map",
        "popup": "index.html"
    },

    "icons": {
        "48": "images/48x48.png",
        "128": "images/128x128.png",
        "256": "images/logo.png"
    }
}
```

**Popup**

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rmd.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="radiationmap">
    <div id="rmlbbg"></div>

    <div id="topnavradiation">
        <ul id="menu">
            <div id="themedrop">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>
                        <button id="cus">Contiguous United States</button>
                    </tr></td>
                    <tr><td>
                        <button id="hawaii">Hawaii</button>
                    </tr></td>
                    <tr><td>
                        <button id="alaska">Alaska</button>
                    </tr></td>
                    <tr><td>
                        <button id="sa">South America</button>
                    </tr></td>
                    <tr><td>
                        <button id="japan">Japan</button>
                    </tr></td>
                    <tr><td>
                        <button id="europe">Europe</button>
                    </tr></td>
                </table>
            </div>
            <li><button id="about">About</button></li>
            <li><button id="home">Home</button></li>
            <li><button id="location">Location</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="radiationmap">
        <div id="cusmap">
            <img src="http://www.radiationnetwork.com/GGFTPMap.jpg" width="752" height="478">
        </div>
        <div id="alaskamap">
            <img src="http://www.radiationnetwork.com/Alaska.JPG" width="752" height="478">
        </div>
        <div id="hawaiimap">
            <img src="http://www.radiationnetwork.com/Hawaii.JPG" width="752" height="478">
        </div>
        <div id="samap">
            <img src="http://www.radiationnetwork.com/Paraguay.JPG" width="752" height="478">
        </div>
        <div id="japanmap">
            <img src="http://www.radiationnetwork.com/Japan.JPG" width="752" height="478">
        </div>
        <div id="europemap">
            <img src="http://www.radiationnetwork.com/Europe.JPG" width="752" height="478">
        </div>

        <table width="752">
            <td><img src="images/LegendWeb.bmp"></td>
            <td><img src="images/Nuclear.bmp"> Nuclear Site</td>
            <td>Alert Level = 100 CPM</td>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="aboutradiationmap">
        Radiation Map is powered by the <a href="http://radiationnetwork.com/" target="_blank">Radiation Network</a>, and without them this extension couldn't be possible.

        <p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/mikethedj4" target="_blank">Michael</a> created this extension for obvious reasons, and is in no way affiliated with the Radiation Network.</p>
        <hr>
        <center>Take control over your life, and stay safe!<br />
        <em>Much Love!</em>

        <p><a href="http://swagbucks.com/refer/mikethedj4" target="_blank"><img src="images/swagbucks.jpg"></a></p>

        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**RMD.JS** (effects to hide, and show other maps that monitor radiation levels)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#alaskamap, div#hawaiimap, div#samap, div#japanmap, div#europemap, div#themedrop, div#aboutradiationmap, div#rmlbbg').hide();

    $('button#home').click(function() {
        $('div#rmlbbg, div#aboutradiationmap').fadeOut(400);
        $('div#themedrop').slideUp(400);
    });

    $('button#about').click(function() {
        $('div#rmlbbg, div#aboutradiationmap').fadeToggle(400);
        $('div#themedrop').slideUp(400);
    });

    $('button#location').click(function() {
        $('div#themedrop').slideToggle(400);
    });

    $('button#cus').click(function() {
        $('div#alaskamap, div#hawaiimap, div#samap, div#japanmap, div#europemap').slideUp(400);
        $('div#cusmap').delay(400).slideDown(400);
    });

    $('button#europe').click(function() {
        $('div#alaskamap, div#hawaiimap, div#samap, div#japanmap, div#cusmap').slideUp(400);
        $('div#europemap').delay(400).slideDown(400);
    });

    $('button#japan').click(function() {
        $('div#alaskamap, div#hawaiimap, div#samap, div#cusmap, div#europemap').slideUp(400);
        $('div#japanmap').delay(400).slideDown(400);
    });

    $('button#sa').click(function() {
        $('div#alaskamap, div#hawaiimap, div#cusmap, div#japanmap, div#europemap').slideUp(400);
        $('div#samap').delay(400).slideDown(400);
    });

    $('button#alaska').click(function() {
        $('div#cusmap, div#hawaiimap, div#samap, div#japanmap, div#europemap').slideUp(400);
        $('div#alaskamap').delay(400).slideDown(400);
    });

    $('button#hawaii').click(function() {
        $('div#alaskamap, div#cusmap, div#samap, div#japanmap, div#europemap').slideUp(400);
        $('div#hawaiimap').delay(400).slideDown(400);
    });

    $('div#rmlbbg').click(function() {
        $('div#rmlbbg, div#aboutradiationmap').fadeOut(400);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The page is reloaded every time the pop-up opens, meaning that state won't persist automatically. You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) to remember the setting for the current session (or even `localStorage` if you want it to survive a browser restart). Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    ...

    $('button#cus').click(function() {
        $('div#alaskamap, div#hawaiimap, div#samap, div#japanmap, div#europemap').slideUp(400);
        $('div#cusmap').delay(400).slideDown(400);
        sessionStorage.selectedMap = "cus";
    });

    ...

    // "Click" the button corresponding to the map previously selected
    var selectedMap = sessionStorage.selectedMap || "cus";
    $('button#' + selectedMap).click();
});
```

Comment: The user opens up the extension, clicks on Alaska, closes the extension, opens it back up, and I'd like it to stay on how the user left it.

Sorry for the confusion, but how does this fixes the issue?

Comment: @mikethedj4: I probably should have been more explicit - what you are asking for won't happen automatically. The page gets reloaded every time the popup opens. So you have to initialize the page in such a way that user's previous choice is respected. That's what my code exemplifies.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit on this answer. Using localStorage preserves the state of the extension when you open and close the extension while sessionStorage does not. I guess opening and closing the extension reopens the popups in a new window/tab so the sessionStorage is cleared.

Comment: Can you save state in the background script via messages?

Comment: @Sukima: You could, especially if your goal is saving persistent state (via `chrome.storage` API). Given that the question was about state for the current session only, `sessionStorage` seems more appropriate - no async logic required, so this approach is simpler.